# How to define if a given set is an universe for a substructure?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Recently we studied the topic about structures at school, but I didn't quite get it. So my task is to check if a given set is an universe for a substructure of F (the structure of the natural numbers), where F = (**N**,+,*), **N** are the natural numbers and + and . are the standard addition and multiplication. Let's say the given set I should check for is {0,1} what steps should I take to determine if this set is a universe for a substructure of F.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is the universe of a structure for a language $L$, and $V \subseteq U$, then for $V$ to be the universe for a substructure, you must verify that $V$ is closed under all functions in the language $L$ (including any constants, which are considered 0-ary functions).  If $V$ wasn't closed under some function, then that function from $L$ wouldn't be defined in $V$, so $V$ wouldn't be a substructure.  In your case, the functions are + and *.  Relations are automatically inherited from the superstructure (since their outputs are true/false rather than an element of the universe), and do not need to be checked.